# custom colors in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hi I have two columns in my dataframe gender, countries

I am trying to get a bar graph of population of countries, for example:
India - Male - 40
- Female-20
US    - Male - 20
- Female-15
.....

I want to give custom color to male and female for example "Blue" for men and "pink" for female, How do I specify color here?

Below is my code:

```
a = df["Gender"]
b = a.groupby(df["Countries"]).value_counts()

b.unstack().plot.bar()

plt.xlabel("Countries")
plt.ylabel("Count of People")
plt.title("Count of genders based on their age Countries")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you sahre part of your data?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [color parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html), for example like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns #To load some data

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df2 = df['species'].groupby(df['species']).value_counts().unstack()

#df2.columns
#Out[29]: Index(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'], dtype='object', name='species')

colors = {column:color for column, color in zip(df2.columns, ['green', 'cyan','blue'])} #Named colors: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html

df2.plot.bar(color=colors)
```

[image]